# Rearranging woocommerce products page

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook

I have a layout for my shop page that looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <aside class="span3">/*sidebar*/</aside>
    <div class="span9">/*product list*/</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In `functions.php` the functions that controls it all look like this

```
function open_woocommerce_content_wrappers(){
    echo '<div class="container"><div class="row">';
}

function close_woocommerce_content_wrappers(){
    echo '</div></div>';
}

function product_wrapper_open(){
    echo '<div class="span9">';
}

function product_wrapper_close(){
    echo '</div>';
}

function before_shop_loop_sidebar() {
    global $theme_options;

    echo '<aside class="span3">'; 
    dynamic_sidebar($theme_options['shop_sidebar']);
    echo '</aside>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'before_shop_loop_sidebar', 10);

function vozx_prepare_woocommerce_wrappers(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);

    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'open_woocommerce_content_wrappers', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'close_woocommerce_content_wrappers', 10 );    
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'product_wrapper_open', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'product_wrapper_close', 10 );
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'prepare_woocommerce_wrappers' );
```

This works, only I'd like to have `span9` with content in it to go first, and `aside` with `span3` to go after `span9`. I've tried changing the priorities, but that only resulted in sidebar inside `span9` content.

I want this layout:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span9">/*product list*/</div>
    <aside class="span3">/*sidebar*/</aside>
    </div>
</div>
```

What should I do?

EDIT:

Figured it out!

I changed

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'before_shop_loop_sidebar', 10);
```

to

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'before_shop_loop_sidebar', 20);
```

This rearranged it :)

Comment: Why don't you actually [override the templates](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)?

Comment: I'm avoiding overriding the templates at all costs, because I've had bad experience when creators updated their plugin, various errors would occur, so with this I'm just making minimal changes (layout, or some small changes).

Comment: I'm not sure how safely overriding a template is any more likely to break things than hard-coded references to hooks is...But you're the developer ;-)

Comment: I had overridden templates that were made with older version of woocommerce, and when I updated it I got a lots of errors. This way all the functions are just from default plugin, so if they update it, the breakage would be minimal :D

Comment: You make your own folder in your theme directory for WooCommerce templates. When you do updates, you just fix it.

Comment: As I've said, I'm trying to avoid the fixing, and let the woocommerce authors do the fixing :D